# Trouble unmarshaling YAML structure

Tags: go, struct, yaml

I have what I think is a very straightforward YAML structure I'm attempting to write to and read from a file.

```
appName:
   version: 1.2.3.4
   md5_checksum: 987654321
```

And I'm really struggling to understand nested structs and how they relate to yaml marshaling.

At this point I have the following:

```
type Application struct {
    Name     string `yaml:"application"`
    Version  string `yaml:"version"`
    Checksum int    `yaml:"md5_checksum"`
}

yamlData := Application{"MyProgram", "1.2.3.4", 34235234123}
y, err := yaml.Marshal(yamlData)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Yaml marshal failed")
}

err = ioutil.WriteFile("applications.yaml", y, 0644)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("File write failed")
}
```

This gets me close, but the file reads as follows:

```
application: MyProgram
version: 1.2.3.4
md5_checksum: 34235234123
```

That looks nice, but this file will be populated by many applications. I've tried a few types of nested structs, but I get hung up on how to supply values to them when finally building them.

Comment: See [example of nested yaml struct](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own problem with help from KibGzr.

No structs necessary just for the marshaling steps.

```
yamlData := map[string]map[string]string{
    appName: map[string]string{"version": appVersion, "md5_checksum": checksumString},
}
```

I've created a nested map rather than a struct. This allows me just initialize the map when I've collected all my values rather than trying to work around struct field names. My output is now:

```
appName:
  md5_checksum: checksumString
  version: appVersion
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can define Application struct as

```
type AppVersion struct {
    Version  string `yaml:"version"`
    Checksum int    `yaml:"md5_checksum"`
}

type Application struct {
    Name AppVersion `yaml:"appName"`
}
```

Then call `AppVersion` as

```
yamlData := Application{Name: AppVersion{Version: "1.2.3.4", Checksum: 34235234123}}
```

Comment: KibGzr, thank you for the succinct answer. My issue now is: how to I include the application name. What I end up with this implemtation is a static "appName"(literal) with nested version and checksum values. My main experience with YAML comes from Ansible, and I'm looking for something similar to the second code block shown here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html